# Can I change my MAC address to be the same as my old MacBook so it will stop rejecting my iPod?

Tags: ipod, mac-address

I was wondering if I could change my MAC address to be the same as my old MacBook so it will stop rejecting my iPod or trying to force me to erase it? Or is it better to just generate an entirely new one? Thanks!

Comment: You can spoof your MAC address pretty easily on OS X, but I'm not sure it'll stop your iPod from being rejected. iTunes is a real PITA when it comes to transferring devices to new computers... If there was ever a area Apple needed to dramatically improve, that would be one.

Comment: I doubt it relies on MAC address at all; as that would be different over wifi as opposed to USB, for instance. Why not just migrate the old machine to the new one?

Comment: Your MAC address (which is a networking acronym for Media Access Control, not an abbreviation of Macintosh, like the name of your computer is) has nothing to do with iTunes "rejecting" your iPod. What exactly is iTunes doing?

Comment: @Tetsujin - USB controllers do not have a MAC address as they are not a networking interface.

Comment: Fair point - but there must be some kind of recognition 'UUID' passed between the devices. Changing the wifi MAC address wouldn't change that anyway. My point was really that changing the MAC wouldn't fix the issue [even if I got the tech-speak wrong;) & that migrating the old data may prevent the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Making the name identical will not change acceptance.
You have to deauthorize the ipod from the old MB and then authorize on the new MB  .